# Cleanup Transfer ORM definitions?

Tags: orm, coldfusion, transfer-orm

Started researching [Transfer ORM](http://www.transfer-orm.com/) recently and find it pretty cool.

Today I've noticed that definitions directory contains some old files from my previous development sessions (ex. 27/08, 28/08). I have only few objects in transfer.xml for that project, but they produced few definition files each already.

Should I worry about them?

Maybe the only reason is that object XML changes, so it's development-only issue.

Will Transfer cleanup these after some period or I should set up the script to do this? If second way, which algorithm would you recommend to avoid removing files in use? Simply remove all of them when going live?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe Transfer deletes old files that it generates. They are safe to delete using any method as they will regenerate the first time they are needed.